# Maximum likelihood estimation in python

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, quantitative-finance, mle

I want to solve this function.

[image]

I want to estimate the parameter in the pin model. The Log converted likelihood function is the same as the attached photo. The parameters to be estimated are (α, δ, μ, εB, εS). I code the 3-steps-for-statement to set initial value. I try to use statsmodel or scipy.minimize to estimate the parameter by applying maximum likelihood estimation. I do not know what parameters to put in detail. Give me an idea..

```
import timeimport random
import sqlite3
from openpyxl import Workbook
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize

def cal_likelihood(mean_selling, mean_buying, selling_array, buying_array):
    final_param = []
    for ini_a in [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9]:
        for ini_h in [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9]:
            for z in [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9]:
                ini_eB = z * mean_buying

                cal_u = (mean_buying - ini_eB) / (ini_a * (1-ini_h))
                ini_eS = mean_selling - (ini_a * ini_h * cal_u)

                i = 0
                for i in range(0, len(buying_array)):
                    k1 = ((-1.0)*(cal_u) - buying_array[i] * scipy.log10(1 + (cal_u/ini_eB)))
                    k2 = ((-1.0)*(cal_u) - selling_array[i] * scipy.log10(1 + (cal_u/ini_eS)))
                    k3 = (-1) * buying_array[i] * scipy.log10(1 + (cal_u/ini_eB)) - selling_array[i] * scipy.log10(1 + (cal_u/ini_eS))
                    kmi = max(k1, k2, k3)

                    ini_L = ini_a * ini_h * scipy.exp(k1 - kmi) + ini_a * (1 - ini_h) * scipy.exp(k2 - kmi) + (1 - ini_a) * scipy.exp(k3 - kmi) + (buying_array[i] * scipy.log10(ini_eB + ini_h) + selling_array[i] * scipy.log10(ini_eS + ini_h) - (ini_eB + ini_eS) + kmi)
```

Comment: α = ini_a, δ = ini_h, μ = cal_u, εB = ini_eB, εS = ini_eS